# Application insights in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have configured ASP .NET 5 application to use application insights. It is a angularjs web application with pure HTML,Java script and no server side code.

Steps followed

1. Added Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights in project.json.
2. Added required javascript in the head section of html.

In the azure portal, except server response time, server request and failed request data, everything else is showing up fine.

I tried two things.

1. Hosted the website in my local machine(behind corportate proxy) with 80 and 443 port opened. Installed Application insights status monitor tool with appinsights enabled for the site.
2. Hosted the site in azure website.

In both the cases, only server response data is not showing up.Find the below screenshot.
[image]

Please help. Am I missing something.?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm thinking there is no automatic server side tracking. You would have to take dependency on the telemetryclient and then use it in your server side code to log what you want https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage/?rnd=1

Comment: if there is any automatics server side logging available I would think it still needs a middleware or something to plug it in to the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your question, you application is a pure client application. Thus, you only get metrics reported by JavaScript code that you probably inserted in your `<head>` tag according to Application Insights guidelines.

You send no requests to your server side, thus there is no occassion for your server-part to send any metrics to Application Insights.

On the other hand, if you had only server application (eg. some web API) with no client part, you would get the three metrics you are currently missing, but no Browser Load Data.

Comment: For a web application which references WebAPI, will it send server side metrics..?

Comment: It does not matter whether it is WebAPI or MVC. You have send some requests to your server side so that Application Insights can log some server side metrics.

Comment: I am getting server side data for MVC application. But I am not getting any data under the servers section.. i.e,Available memory, Process IO rate, Exception rate.. should I configure anything separately for that..?

Comment: for the "servers" information, you might either need the AI performance collector package installed, or you might also need Application Insights Status Monitor installed on the server (and make sure your web apps service account is in the right windows security group to get the performance counter data, the perf readers group I think)